# How to react to change in data in a service in angularjs on a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I want to be able to share data between two controllers so that I can send a boolean to the service from the first controller which is turn triggers a change in the second controller.

Here is what the service looks like

```
exports.service = function(){

// sets Accordion variable to false ;

var property = true;

return {
    getProperty: function () {
        return property;
    },
    setProperty: function(value) {
        property = value;
    }
};
```

};

Now the first controller

exports.controller = function($scope, CarDetailsService, AccordionService ) {

```
    $scope.saveDetails = function() {

            AccordionService.setProperty(false);

    }
```

}

and the second one

```
exports.controller = function($scope, AccordionService ) {

    $scope.isCollapsed = AccordionService.getProperty();

}
```

The use case is that when i click on a button on the first controller,the service updates the data inside it, which is then served on the second controller, thus triggering a change in the second controller.

I have been looking around for quite some time but couldn't find a solution to this. Maybe im just stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second controller you can $watch the variable you change in the first:

```
scope.$watch('variable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   //React to the change
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on the rootScope:

On the first controller:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("NEW_EVENT", data);
```

On the other controller:

```
scope.$on("NEW_EVENT", function(event, data){
           //use the data
        });
```

Comment: You won't pollute the $rootScope with variables, but you can use it to broadcast or emit events on other scopes